# Why isn't my PHP code posting to my SQL-Database?

Tags: php, mysql, password-protection, password-hash

I am pretty sure that I don't have any errors, however, when I submit the from, I don't get a "Success" like I should when my submission is successful. The connect.php is the php file that connects to my database, and I don't get any errors from that, so I know that I am connected to my database and the header.php is the header. Nothing that would cause any errors in there. And the footer is the same thing. I know that I am connected to my database because I got an error before when I was testing my code, however, now I don't get any errors, or a "Success".

Here is my attempt:

```
<?php
//signup.php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';

echo '<h3>Sign up</h3>';
echo '<form method="post" action="">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user_name" />
    Password: <input type="password" name="user_pass">
    Password again: <input type="password" name="user_pass_check">
    E-mail: <input type="email" name="user_email">
    <input type="submit" value="sign up" />
</form>';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $fixed_user_name = $database_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
    $fixed_user_email = $database_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']);
    $now = NOW();

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_pass, user_email) 
            VALUES ($fixed_user_name, $_POST['user_pass'], $fixed_user_email)";

    if($database_connection->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "Success";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $database_connection->error;
    }
}

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

Here is my connect.php file, as well:

```
<?php
//connect.php
$username   = 'root';
$password   = "root_password";
$database   = 'cloud';

$database_connection = new mysqli("localhost", $username, $password, $database);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

?>
```

Comment: What is in the `$database_connection->error` then? Syntax error?

Comment: Enable error reporting and try again. Add following line on top of your page
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries.Escaping strings aren't as secure as one would hope. Specially since you'e only escaping some inputs!??

Comment: **Don't**... store... passwords... in... plain... text!

Comment: you may also echo the $sql and try to execute it using phpmyadmin just in case the password you entered contains characters that mess up the query

Comment: the problem are your quotes "" and ''

Comment: Btw, you never compare `user_pass` and `user_pass_check`.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson included that in my answer :)

Comment: This is all for demonstration purposes and will not be published without taking the proper precautions. I just wanted to get a rough version working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a more secure way to your script with password_hash() and prepared-statements:
<kbd>signup.php</kbd>

```
<?php
//signup.php

#include "connect.php"; // set $servername, $username, $password and $dbname there

include 'header.php';

// changed here the '' to "" and back
echo "<h3>Sign up</h3>".
    "<form method='post' action=''>
        Username: <input type='text' name='user_name' />
        Password: <input type='password' name='user_pass'>
        Password again: <input type='password' name='user_pass_check'>
        E-mail: <input type='email' name='user_email'>
        <input name='submit' type='submit' value='sign up' />
     </form>";

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    include "connect.php";

    // set the user_name and user_email as a seperate variable
    $username = $_POST["user_name"];
    $email = $_POST["user_email"];
    $password = $_POST["user_pass"];
    $cpassword = $_POST["user_pass_check"];

    $fixed_user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $username);

    $fixed_user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $email);

    #$now = NOW();

    //check if password is not cpassword and if so, there is an error
    if ($password !== $cpassword) {
        echo "Passwords do not match!";
    }

    //NEVER store PLAINTEXT PASSWORDS... user php build_in functions like password_hash() and store only the hash
    $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    //change your db_entry user_pass to hash
    $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_name, hash, user_email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $sql->bind_param("sss", $fixed_user_name, $hash, $fixed_user_email);
    $sql->execute();

    echo "Success!";

    $sql->close();
    $conn->close();

}
include 'footer.php';
?>
```

<kbd>connect.php</kbd>

```
<?php
//connect.php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "root_password";
$dbname   = "cloud";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

explanation is in the script with comments :)

have a look at [php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for password_hash() function

maybe this helped you

Comment: To make it even more secure, and safe from SQL injections, use Prepared Statements...

Comment: yeah but i thought this would be enouth for the beginning and understanding

Comment: I generally disagree. It's better to do it correctly from the start, but I agree that the password issue was the most important, so I understand why you skipped the prepared statements. :)

Comment: So, I tested your script, and added my information to login to my database, and it ran without any errors when I propagated the form, however, it still did not propagate the information in my database. When I view the table, it has no rows.

Edit:
It also does not echo the "Success!".

Comment: @Joshua can yo poast an image of your db ? and the db create_code ?

Comment: [Database](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0T4Zd3yJU37Z2xra1JsYkxqNWs)
[Screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0T4Zd3yJU37Wm5CU1FFNnY4YzA)

Comment: Then why is it not adding a user to the table?

Comment: your connection is not passing :P make a screenshot of the connect.php and show it to me

Comment: @Joshua can you post the code from that file in your question ? i will change it so that it will work. and add it into my answer here

Comment: @Joshua now it's live. just copy and past the code into your files and save it. and then it should work :)

Comment: Okay. I ran it, and I didn't get any errors, however, it still didn't post to the database.

Comment: Also, if I enter two different passwords, it doesn't return the password error.

Comment: yeah i made a mistake ... i'll test it and correct it to myself and then update and let you know

Comment: I'm still getting nothing. Nothing on the page changes. It doesn't even add the "?" to the url when I click submit.

Comment: @Blueblazer172 P.S. I really appreciate all the help.

Comment: what system are you running ?

Comment: ah dude we missed the `name='submit'`

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with LAMP stack.

Comment: @Blueblazer172 That is by far the most satisfying feeling in the world. Thank you so much. It now works! Now I just have to work on signing users in. That'll be fun. Again, thank you so much for the help. Do you mind if I contact you directly in the event that I need more help on this project?

Comment: @Joshua feel free for contacting me :) btw can you accept my answer? :P

Comment: @Blueblazer172 Absolutely, I will accept your answer. +15 rep for you. :)

Comment: @Joshua thanks :) feel free for inviting me in the stackexchange-chat if you have any other problems

Comment: @Blueblazer172 How would I contact you directly in the future?

Comment: skype ? email ? depents on you

Comment: i'll write a testmail now :)

Comment: @Joshua mail's out

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<h3>Sign up</h3>';
echo '<form method="post" action="">
Username: <input type="text" name="user_name" />
Password: <input type="password" name="user_pass">
Password again: <input type="password" name="user_pass_check">
E-mail: <input type="email" name="user_email">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="sign up" />
</form>';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$fixed_user_name = $database_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_name']);
$fixed_user_email = $database_connection->real_escape_string($_POST['user_email']);
$now = NOW();

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_pass, user_email) 
        VALUES ('$fixed_user_name', '".$_POST['user_pass']."', '$fixed_user_email')";

$result = mysqli_query(whatever your connection variable is, $sql);

if($database_connection->query($sql) === TRUE){
    echo "Success";
}
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $database_connection->error;
}
}
```

Comment: Try the appended, sorry it's really difficult for me to write code in that tiny box :) I'm not familiar with php 7 but this should work, you should put your query in another file and put the file in the action="" part of the form.

Comment: Okay. I did that, and now it just takes me to a blank page with the name of the file in the url... I'll try your updated code next.

Comment: Okay. I tried your updated code, and I get the same thing. Except it takes away the footer.php information that was there... And I still have a blank database table.

Comment: well it will take you to a blank page because there is nothing on your query page except php, but if the query was a success, use header('Location: index.php'); at the end of your query.